# Is it a problem if my Windows partition is visible from within Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I'm a longtime Ubuntu user but I would still call myself a Linux beginner.

I just bought a new laptop with Windows 10 installed, and installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 to dual boot alongside it.  I can boot into both OS's fine, but I notice that when I boot into Ubuntu, my Windows partition automatically mounts under /media/my_user/OS.  Is that a problem?  Specifically, does the fact that Windows is visible from Ubuntu mean that the two OS's are not sufficiently compartmentalized (e.g. is there a risk that I'll unknowingly overwrite Windows data as I use Ubuntu or vice versa)?

Comment: would you preffer to not have your windows drive mount?

Comment: *Please do not run the command in the comment above!* It will severely damage your Windows installation if it's mounted in the specified directory by deleting all DLL files.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.  I don't want the windows partition mounting automatically.  From what you've all said, it sounds like all I have to do is tell Ubuntu not to mount the partition on boot (as opposed to having to re-do the Ubuntu install because I did something wrong), correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** there is a *risk*, but it should be small. Just having the partitions mounted will not cause any problems, but if you write data to them or change them then you can cause problems.

For example, if you were to delete all the files in the windows partition while running Linux, you would not be able to boot into windows.

For the most part, things will go along the lines of common sense. Don't delete or change windows programs or components and everyone remains happy.

There are a couple of exceptions. First encrypted files and folders in windows will look like gibberish in Linux. Messing with those will damage them. And if you "suspend" windows and boot into Linux, doing almost any write operation on the windows partition has the ability to cause data loss. (This is one reason you should turn off fast boot in the bios).

Of course "global" disk changes like partitioning and  formatting will cause data loss if not done correctly. Some data recovery or file system tools will cause an issue too.

So in the end,

There are risks, but they are much the same as if you dual booted windows 8 and windows 10 and started monkeying around with "the other" install. Your day to day stuff should be 100% safe, just watch your self as you do file system operations and be aware of write operations. Good advise no matter the OS or file system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really.

Essentially, Ubuntu sees that drive as an external storage medium - just like a USB or an external hard drive:

[image]

See how my 234 GB volume is mounted with

So the risk of writing over data on your Windows partition is essentially the same as writing over on a USB. Pretty low. To overwirte it you would either have to be in a terminal and `cp` / `mv` / `rm` something in `/media/user/OS` which would be quite difficult, or drag a file there and click the "replace".

[image]